# jQuery validator addMethod not working with dropdownList

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have DropDownListFor in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PeriodCode,..., new { name = "Period", id = "PeriodID"})
```

And my validation as follows:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('NonEmpty', function (value) {
    return ($("#PeriodID").val() != "");
}, '');

jQuery("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        Year: {
            required: true
        },
        Period: {
            NonEmpty: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Year: {
            required: "<div style='color:red'>Message 1 </div>"
        },
        Period: {
            NonEmpty: "<div style='color:red'>Message 2 </div>"
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that `jQuery AddMethod` function is not invoked when i submit my form, so my `DropDownList` is not validated. However validation for the `TextBox` with the name `'Year'` works fine. What am I doing wrong?

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: What is the point of the `NonEmpty` method, when it is performing the the same logic as `required` does?

Comment: Yes, the value of DDL should not be null or empty string.

Comment: That's my point - the built in `required` validator will check that for you.

Comment: I would like to use custom validator, as the message of built in one is not appropriate for me

Comment: And yet in your example you're using the same message for both...? I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood required validator with class = 'required'. I tried to use it, but it does not validate DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `$` before the selector `("#PeriodID")`.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('NonEmpty', function (value) {
    return ($("#PeriodID").val() != "");
}, '');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9VgLL/)

Anyway the validator rule must be like - the rule should not hard code any element, it has to validate the value passed to it

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('NonEmpty', function (value, elem, args) {
    return value != "";
}, '');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dR722/)

*Note: There is no need to a add such a rule since it can be achieved by using the `required` rule*

**Update:** the name of the period field is not `Period` it is `PeriodCode`

```
jQuery("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        Year: {
            required: true
        },
        PeriodCode: {
            NonEmpty: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Year: {
            required: "<div style='color:red'>Message 1 </div>"
        },
        PeriodCode: {
            NonEmpty: "<div style='color:red'>Message 2 </div>"
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RjhUM/2), [with required rule](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RjhUM/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that the method is not being invoked, if I put alert() inside the method it will not appear.

Comment: @GyuzalRakhmayeva can you try to recreate the issue using the attached fiddles

Comment: @Arun .val() returns the value
if value is not specified in options it would return null...

Comment: @GyuzalRakhmayeva can you share the generated html for the select element

Comment: @GyuzalRakhmayeva the name of the field is not `Period` it is `PeriodCode`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Perfect! I thougth it should take another 'name' that I defined. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('select[id=PeriodID] option:selected').text();
```

instead of

```
("#PeriodID").val()
```

Comment: Why we need to validate again `text`? Hope it should be validated with `value` property of `option`, which is `val()`

Answer (score 0):

If your addMethod hook is not being registered, it is likely because you have the code within a DOM Ready handler or, perhaps, a closure.  Try moving the code outside of any lambdas; you should then be able to get the code to run as desired.

See [ASP .Net MVC 3: Custom unobtrusive validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245872/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-unobtrusive-validation) for more details.  It is specific to the "unobtrusive" library, but the reasoning is the same.